# Does Visual Studio Tools for Office require Office to be installed?

Tags: ms-office, vsto

Does Visual Studio Tools for Office require Office to be installed in order to work with excel files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=F5539A90-DC41-4792-8EF8-F4DE62FF1E81&displaylang=en) say the following:

Version of Microsoft Office: Developing and running Office customizations built with VSTO 2005 or VSTO 2005 SE **requires at least one of the following versions of Microsoft Office**

- Microsoft Office Professional Edition 2003
- Microsoft Office Standard Edition 2003 (only application-level add-ins work with Standard Edition)
- Microsoft Word 2003
- Microsoft Excel 2003
- Microsoft InfoPath 2003
- Microsoft Outlook 2003
- Microsoft Office Visio 2003
- Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2003
- 2007 Microsoft Office system
- Microsoft Office Word 2007
- Microsoft Office Excel 2007
- Microsoft Office Outlook 2007
- Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007
- Microsoft Office Visio 2007
- Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx)

> The Microsoft Office primary interop assemblies must be installed into the global assembly cache (GAC) and registered before you can create or run a Visual Studio Tools for Office solution. You can then write managed code to interact with a Microsoft Office application's COM-based object model. For more information, see [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx)

This second link states:

> You can install the complete set of primary interop assemblies in the global assembly cache in two ways:
>
> - Perform a Complete installation of Microsoft Office.
> - Install them from the redistributable primary interop assemblies package.

This redistributable can be [downloaded from here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=72637)